# How to pass string containing url in query string from android

Tags: android, query-string, url-encoding

I need to post string containing url to the server I have able to encoding the url but this will encoding whole string and I need to require only url link to be encoded and decode when get this data back to display in android.

```
mydomain/post.php?mesg=Hello%2Bhow%2Br%2Bu%250A%2BHttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%250A%250ATesting%2Burl
```

**Edited**

My code

```
String postStr = "Hello how r u?
                  http://www.google.com"; // suppose user entered string like this way

Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
    .scheme("http")
    .authority(domain)
    .path(pageName)
    .appendQueryParameter("mesg", URLEncoder.encode(postStr, "utf-8"))
String urlStr = builder.build().toString();
```

After executing this getting this result

```
Hello+how+r+u%0A+Http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%0A%0ATesting+url
```

And actual result want like this

```
Hello how r u?
http://www.google.com

Testing url
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.Uri.Builder;

String reqUrl = "http://google.com"
Builder builder = Uri.parse(reqUrl).buildUpon();
builder.appendQueryParameter("mesg", "Value for mesg");
String finalUri = builder.build().toString();
```

Comment: Then what you need is: URLEncoder.encode is from package: java.net.URLEncoder;

Comment: I dont get what is your problem, you need to send your values in the url encoded. The decoding may be in the server side. Why you want to send a decoded url?

Comment: I have dynamic string like in my question and want to post this string to server now if I encoding whole string then getting result hello+how+r like this but I want Hello how r u? etc like this way

Answer (score 1):

Try using Beloq Way

you should not encode whole String containing URL.just encode the Part you want to encode and decode.i think below is the Way to go. try it out. though i am not Sure this is the thing you are looking for.

```
String name=URLEncoder.encode("Hello hw are you?")+"http://www.google.com"+URLEncoder.encode("Testing url");
```

Hope it will Help somehow.

Comment: u r encoding the string not the url I want only encoding the string url not whole string and string was dynamic which entered by the user

Answer (score 0):

Build the dynamic string separating url and the text. For instance, you could do like

```
String postStr = Hello how r u? %& http://www.google.com
```

As you can see, I used a combination of symbols as separator.

Now use split the string,

```
String[] values = postStr.split("%&");
```

You could also use StringTokenizer class!

Hope this helps!